# Telnet not properly displaying text?

Tags: windows, terminal, telnet

I've recently discovered and started playing nethack. I know I can play it locally, but I'm sitting at different computers all the time so I found nethack.alt.org that let's you telnet into their servers to play the ASCII art terminal game. On most computers, the telnet session appears fine and I have no problems. But on my main laptop, some things don't display correctly. I don't telnet into anything else (RDP and VPN meet my usual needs) so my only point of reference is this nethack server.

The biggest visible malformations is when I go to look at the list of running games. The game however looks just fine.

[image: malformed table in telnet]

This should be a neatly laid out table (as it is on every computer other than my laptop). As I move up and down the list, the rows tend to be added to the bottom of the window instead of updated in place.

I wish I had other examples outside of this game to say why my telnet is messed up. I don't know where to look. My cmd is at the normal 80x25 dimensions, changing any of the Edit Options doesn't seem to impact this. What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely incorrect terminal emulation.

I can confirm the same behavior for the games list on `nethack.alt.org` on my Windows 7 system using Microsoft's telnet.

Windows telnet should default to [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) emulation. Apparently, sometimes it does not. You can force the right emulation, however by running `telnet` without arguments, using the `set term vt100` command to explicitly set emulation, and then opening the connection:

```
c:\> telnet
...
Microsoft Telnet> set term vt100
...
Microsoft Telnet> open nethack.alt.org
```

See the [Telnet documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Telnet-commands) for more information.

You may always want to check out [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), which is a much better client than Microsoft's.

Comment: I second the recommendation to use putty

Comment: I know of putty and acknowledge it as a great tool. However, given this is my only use of telnet (and that your fix works) I probably won't be installing it on this computer. I'm glad you brought it up though.

Comment: You can just download the single `putty.exe` and execute it directly. It doesn't need installing.